# Best mocking framework for Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mocking

What is the best mocking framework for Silverlight 5?

I used to use Moq, but I found that it does not work with Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/blog/3843/rhino-mocks-3-5-silverlight)?
We are using the same but we are on SL4, I don't think it breaks on SL5 either.